# Why would a class need move operations to bind to a std::function that has a signature in which the class is passed by value?

Tags: c++, std-function

In the following code:

```
struct X
{
    X() = default;
    X(const X&) { printf("copy construct\n"); }
    X& operator=(const X&) { printf("copy assign\n"); return *this; }
    X(X&&) { printf("move construct\n"); }
    X& operator=(X&&) { printf("move assign\n"); return *this; }
// Replacing the above two lines with these lines below causes a compile error.
//    X(X&&) = delete;
//    X& operator=(X&&) = delete;
};

void f(X x) {}

int main()
{
    X x;
    std::function<void (X)> fx(f);
    f(x);

    return 0;
}
```

if I define struct X to have copy and move operations, then a std::function with signature void (X) is able to bind to it. But if I delete the move operations, the code doesn't compile any more, with this error:

```
prog.cc:26:29: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::function<void (X)>'
    std::function<void (X)> fx(f);
 candidate template ignored: requirement '__callable<void (*&)(X), false>::value' was not satisfied [with _Fp = void (*)(X)]
    function(_Fp);
```

I'm just trying to understand why are the move operations required if the signature describes a function where X is passed by value?

Comment: You made the move constructor available to overload resolution by defining it (as deleted in this case).
It is a better match than the copy constructor in this case, which is deleted and therefore leads to the error message.

Comment: The error is real (as AF_cpp commented), but the error message is terrible.  Explicitly marking them as `= delete` is still subject to overload resolution, whereas omitting them entirely they don't exist at all.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.elision#3
Here is the rule which makes the move constructor a candidate in overload resolution.
Yes the error messages does not really help..

Comment: @AF_cpp Where in the code is the OP calling code in which a move would happen?  `f(x);` will make a copy as `x` is an lvalue.

Comment: @NathanOliver "overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue. If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object's type (possibly cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue." 

timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.elision#3

Comment: @AF_cpp That only applies to `return` or `throw`.

Comment: @NathanOliver The move would have occurred when `fx(x)` would attempt to forward its argument to the target function pointer. Now, the example doesn't actually call `fx` - but `std::function`'s constructor taking a callable is constrained so that it only participates in overload resolution if such a call would be well-formed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::function<void (X)> fx(f)` constructor invocation is ill-formed.

First, the requirements on this constructor:

> **[func.wrap.func.con]**
> `template<class F> function(F f);`
> 7 *Constraints:* `F` is Lvalue-Callable (20.14.16.2) for argument types `ArgTypes...` and return type `R`.
>
> **[func.wrap.func]/2** A callable type (20.14.2) `F` is Lvalue-Callable for argument types `ArgTypes` and return type `R` if the expression
> `INVOKE<R>(declval<F&>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...)`, considered as an unevaluated operand (7.2), is well-formed (20.14.3).

I believe that `f` is not in fact Lvalue-Callable for argument types `X`, however strange this may sound. This hinges on the definition of `declval`:

> **[declval]**
> `template<class T> add_rvalue_reference_t<T> declval() noexcept;`

So, the type of `declval<X>()` is actually `X&&`, not `X`. A call `f(declval<X>())` would need to move from this rvalue reference to a by-value parameter - but the move constructor is declared deleted. And indeed, `sizeof(f(std::declval<X>()), 0);` [fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/Gdv71d7Eb), also complaining about the deleted move constructor.

In other words, `std::function<void (X)> fx(f)` is ill-formed for essentially the same reasons that `X x; f(std::move(x));` is ill-formed.

---

Practically speaking, `std::function::operator()` needs to be able to forward its arguments to the wrapped callable, and uses `std::forward` for that - which would also turn an rvalue into an rvalue reference and expect to be able to move the argument.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this. So I understand that it is ill-formed by language definition (thanks for the explanation). But is that then just something they missed while defining `std::function`? I mean, for the example the OP shows, `X` doesn't need a move constructor to be used in `f()`. Should there be a variant of `std::function` that doesn't require it?

Comment: @JHBonarius It just doesn't make sense to have an object that's copyable but not movable; and so there's no reason for the standard library to go out of its way to cater to a pathological case.

Comment: isn't something like `std::array` copyable but not specifically movable?

Comment: @JHBonarius It's movable, in the sense that `std::array<int, 42> x; std::array<int, 42> y = std::move(x);` compiles. Yes, for this type a move is equivalent to a copy - but that's exactly the point: if an object can be copied, then it can also be moved - at worst, it'd just be a copy with no added efficiency. It doesn't make sense to allow copying but explicitly prohibit moving.